# Show that $P(W_t \in [-1,1] \; \forall t \geq 0) = 0$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

> Show that $P(W_t \in [-1,1] \; \forall t \geq 0) =  0$ where $W_t$ is a standard Wiener process on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.

My attempt:

It holds that $W_t = W_t - 0 = W_t - W_0 \sim N(0,t) \Longrightarrow \dfrac{W_t}{\sqrt{t}} \sim N(0,1)$. So we have

\begin{aligned}
P(W_t \in [-1,1]) &= P(-1 \leq W_t \leq 1) = P\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \leq \frac{W_t}{\sqrt{t}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right) \\ &= \Phi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right) - \Phi\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right) = \Phi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right) - \left(1 - \Phi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)\right)\\
&= 2\Phi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right) - 1
\end{aligned}

but this obviously does not equal $0$ for all $t\geq 0$.

Anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong? I recently started to study Stochastic processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that for any $s$,
$$P( W_t \in [-1, 1], \forall t) \leq P(W_s \in [-1,1]) = 2\Phi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\right) - 1.$$
Send $s \to \infty$!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up $$P(W_t \in [-1,1] \; \forall t \geq 0) =  0$$ with $$P(W_t \in [-1,1] ) =  0 \; \; \forall t \geq 0$$ The quantifier "$\forall t\geq 0$" is inside the probability, so you can let $t\to\infty$ in the expression you found, which does give an answer of $0$.

Comment: The quantifier is informal, but the intersection  $\cap_{t \in [0,\infty)} \{W_t \in [-1,1]\}$ is well-defined and has probability 0, so it is probably what he or she meant.

Comment: @nullUser I would agree that we have an equality of events $$\{W_t \in [-1,1] \; \forall t\geq 0\} = \bigcap_{t\geq 0} \{W_t \in [-1,1]\}$$ but this doesn't address OP's confusion when they say "but this obviously does not equal 0 for all t≥0.  Anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong?"  This confusion is specifically what I was addressing, and in this regard, the quantifier is actually the crux of the problem.

Comment: I see, I solved the exercise, but you answered the real question.

Comment: To be honest I was not sure that my way of solving the exercise was correct, so I was in need of help for solving the exercise and explaining what I was doing wrong. I appreciate both of your comments!